# Detect a memory leak in java on Android

Tags: java, android, websocket, heap-memory

I am trying to run a websocket server in android. It is working perfetct in windows but i am getting a heap overflow in android. What can be the reason?
The message in logcat is

```
07-15 03:29:09.608: D/dalvikvm(2169): GC_CONCURRENT freed 427K, 9% free 6898K/7559K, paused 13ms+6ms
07-15 03:29:10.668: D/dalvikvm(2169): GC_CONCURRENT freed 418K, 9% free 6898K/7559K, paused 13ms+5ms
07-15 03:29:11.760: D/dalvikvm(2169): GC_CONCURRENT freed 418K, 9% free 6898K/7559K, paused 13ms+12ms
07-15 03:29:12.758: D/dalvikvm(2169): GC_CONCURRENT freed 416K, 9% free 6901K/7559K, paused 8ms+8ms
```

Comment: gc is kicks in to free memory those are pause times that you see when gc kicks in to free memory. 13ms+6ms.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. check this video you will know the reason. when heap is full and app requires memory the gc kicks in to free memory.

Comment: GC logs doesn't mean that your app has memory leak. It means you have allocated and deallocated memory which the GC has now cleaned up. If its a leak, your app will still have some reference to memory which it doesn't need and eventually, your app will crash with out of memory exception. But looking at the logs itself you can't tell that. Of course if your app is reaching the heap threshold, the gc will kick in more aggressively in an attempt to prevent your app crashing.

Comment: will it help if i increase the memory(RAM and VM Heap) of the emulator which i am using?

Comment: To find memory leaks, you can trigger GC from ddms at fixed periods and analyze the gc dumps using MAT (Memory Analyser Tool). If you don't know/want to learn using MAT, you can try using another tool: http://littleeye.co to visually see app's memory growth. If you see your app's memory consumption close to the max heap limit most of the time, only then will you need to increase the heap size. Disclaimer: I'm associated with littleeye

Answer (score 1):

“ It is working perfetct in windows but i am getting a heap overflow in android. ” because of the memory limit is different between the two devices.

GC will free momory frequently when the memory is about to be used out.The log is normal because your phone has smaller memory for the code than your pc has.